# How to inherit constructors? OR how to make similar constructors?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, constructor

I am making a class for a character with several attributes. I made it so the user has to choose between 3 objects made from the constructor of that first class.
I cant think of a way to choose between the objects so I want to create a class that inherits the attributes of the first class(basically a copycat) but will only copy the chosen object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Character {
    public:
        string weapon;
        float HP;
        float MP;
        float str;
        float def;

        Character(string aweapon, float aHP, float aMP, float astr, float adef){
            weapon = aweapon;
            HP = aHP;
            MP = aMP;
            str = astr;
            def = adef;
        }
};

class Chose : public Character{
    
};

int main()
{

    Character warrior("sword", 100, 20, 50, 50);

    Character tank("shield", 200, 20, 25, 80);

    Character magician("staff", 80, 100, 30, 30);

    Chose that; // error is here

    cout << warrior.HP << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

error says:-

```
|24|error: no matching function for call to 'Character::Character()'
|15|candidates are:
|15|note: Character::Character(std::string, float, float, float, float)
|15|note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 0 provided
|7|note: Character::Character(const Character&)
|7|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
|39|note: synthesized method 'Chose::Chose()' first required here
```

Sooooo, I can't figure out the problem here.

Comment: What does "but will only copy the chosen object" mean, exactly. `Character that=warrior;`, for example?

Comment: `Chose that; // error is here` A `Chose` object has a `weapon`, `HP`, `MP`, and other values.  You wrote this code so a `Character` can not be created without supplying these parameters.  What should those values be?  It's not clear what you want the line `Chose that;` to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
class Chose : public Character{
public:
    using Character::Character;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TEG7Pvdxa

Note that you are trying use default constructor of `Character` which was removed since custom constructor was defined. As result default constructor of `Chose` can't be created implicitly (since base class  do not have default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

sorry everyone, I found out the answer. But i thank everyone who went out of there way to answer this question.

I simply forgot to add brackets here `Chose that;`
it should be `Chose that();`
also we can add more info like

```
    Chose that("sword", 100, 20, 50, 50);
```

Comment: This still doesn't fixing the issue. See my answer and link provided.